# Diplomacy - Movement question

Tags: diplomacy

Lets say we have

- F Bar-StP
- F Nwy S F Bar-StP
- F StP-Nwy

Does the support from Norway get cut from the fleet in St. Petersburg?  And as such stopping the movement of the Fleet in the Barents sea from moving into St. Petersburg?

Comment: Please clarify if these are the orders of one country or two and if so, which orders belong to which country

Answer (score 6):

If these are all orders from one country, nothing happens.  From [the rules](https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/diplomacy.pdf):

> A country cannot dislodge or support the dislodgement of one of its own units

If "F StP -> Nwy" is a different country from the other two orders, the unit in StP is dislodged.  From the rules:

> Support is cut if the unit giving support is attacked from any province **except the one where support is being given**.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not cut support to your own attack.

I tried this in jDip and the result was that the support was not cut. The fleet from Bar went to StP and the fleet in StP was destroyed.

This is logical else you could stop two units with a single unit.